# Java: Using Regular Expressions to Extract various number of values in a String

Tags: java, regex, extract

I want to write a function to extract various number of values from a String according to a regex pattern:

Here is my function code:

```
/**
 * Get substrings in a string using groups in regular expression.
 * 
 * @param str
 * @param regex
 * @return
 */
public static String[] regexMatch(String str, String regex) {
    String[] rtn = null;
    if (str != null && regex != null) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            int nGroup = matcher.groupCount();
            rtn = new String[nGroup];
            for (int i = 0; i < nGroup; i++) {
                rtn[i] = matcher.group(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

When I test it using:

```
String str = "nets-(90000,5,4).dat";
String regex = "(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)";
String[] rtn = regexMatch(str, regex);
```

I get:

```
rtn: [90000,5,4,90000,5]
```

How can I get rtn to be [90000,5,4] as I expected?

Comment: You could restructure your solution a little by removing everything except commas and numbers and then split on commas. However, this depends on the other strings you process having a similar structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array currently store

```
[0] -> 90000,5,4
[1] -> 90000
[2] -> 5
```

That is why you are seeing as output `[90000,5,4,90000,5]`. It is because `group(0)` represents entire match so it returns `90000,5,4`.

What you need is match from groups 1, 2 and 3.

```
(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)
   1      2      3
```

So change

```
rtn[i] = matcher.group(i);
```

to

```
rtn[i] = matcher.group(i+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would start the for loop with 1 so you can get the grouping you are declaring in your regex. The loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= nGroup; i++) {
            rtn[i] = matcher.group(i);
        }
```

Group 0 is known to be the entire matching string for your regex. The grouping is from:

```
String regex = "(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)";
```

You would say matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), and matcher.group(3)  will give you what you want.

Comment: If OP will start loop with `1` then returned array will not fill `[0]` and you will try to fill `[length]`. Unless you will write it as `rtn[i-1] = matcher.group(i);` which will be variation of my answer.

Comment: this would produce an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I should start from 0 to nGroup-1 I feel.

Comment: true dat, matcher.groupCount() doesnt include index 0 as part of it.